# Click on multiple elements with same ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

My JSP generates two buttons with same id, but when I click on it I want just the one I click on to change style.
This is my JSPcode:

```
<%for(MetodoPagamentoBean m : result){%>    
  <button class="method-1" id="metodo-pagamento-scelto">
    <span><ion-icon name="card"></ion-icon><ion-icon class="checkmark" name="checkmark-circle" id="carta-scelta" style="display:none;"></ion-icon></span>
    <span><b>Numero:</b> <%= "XXXX XXXX XXXX " + m.getNumeroCarta().substring(m.getNumeroCarta().length()-4) %></span>
    <span><b>Intestatario:</b> <%= m.getNomeIntestatario()%></span>
  </button>
 <%} %>
```

while my jQuery is:

```js
$("#metodo-pagamento-scelto").click(function(){
  $("#carta-scelta").show();
  $("#metodo-pagamento-scelto").css("border", "2px solid green");
});
```

How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: `$("#metodo-pagamento-scelto").css` -> `$(this).css` - though your code will only work for the first button anyway.

Answer (score 2):

- Fix your JSP. Creating multiple elements with the same ID is clear sign of poor programming and markup habits. Use classes instead: `class="metodo-pagamento-scelto"`
- Don't use `.css()` when not necessary. Use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` or `addClass()` instead.
- Use `this` in jQuery like `$(this)` to refer to the event currentTarget Element

```js
$(".metodo-pagamento-scelto")     // Use classes
  .on("click", function() {       // Use the .on() Method
    $("#carta-scelta").show();
    $(this).addClass("active");   // Use $(this) to refer to the clicked button
  });
```

CSS:

```css
.metodo-pagamento-scelto.active {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```